# Numerical methods for minimum time optimal problems

Tags: numerical-methods, optimal-control

I have the next optimal problem and I want to make your numerical approximation.

[image]

Reviewing some references, it is mentioned that numerical methods must also be used to solve the dynamic equation and the attached equation.

What numerical methods do you recommend me to use for this kind of problem?

Any bibliographical reference is also welcome.